# Avoiding loops when using NumPy's sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I often need to do summations over certain rows or columns of a larger NumPy array. For example, take this array:

```
>>> c = np.arange(18).reshape(3, 6)
>>> print(c)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

Suppose I want to sum only where the row index is 0 or 2, AND the column index is either 0, 2, 4, or 5. In other words, I want the sum of the subarray

```
[[ 0  2  4  5]
 [12 14 16 17]]
```

I generally do this with NumPy's incredibly useful `ix_` method; e.g.

```
>>> np.sum(c[np.ix_([0,2],[0,2,4,5])])
70
```

So far, so good. Now, however, suppose I have a different array, `e`, that is like `c`, but has two leading dimensions. So its shape is (2,3,3,6) instead of just (3,6):

```
e = np.arange(108).reshape(2, 3, 3, 6)
```

*(Please note that the actual arrays I am working with might contain any random integers; they do not contain consecutive integers like this example.)*

What I'm looking to do is the calculation above for *each* row/column combination. The following works for this simple example, but for larger arrays with more dimensions this can be really, really slow:

```
new_sum = np.empty((2,3))
for i in range(2):
   for j in range(3):
      temp_array = e[i,j,:,:]
      new_sum[i,j] = np.sum(temp_array[np.ix_([0,2],[0,2,4,5])])
```

**The question:** Can the above be accomplished in a faster way, presumably without resorting to using loops?

As a footnote, the result of the above is the following:

```
>>> print(new_sum)
[[ 70. 214. 358.]
 [502. 646. 790.]]
```

Of course, the 70 in the upper-left is the same result we got before.

Comment: `indices=[[0,2], [0,2,4,5]]` and then `np.sum(e[np.ix_(*[range(i) for i in e.shape[:-2]], *indices)], axis=(-2,-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean matrix (mask) that will have `True` on values you want to keep and `False` on those that you don't want.

```
>>> mask = np.zeros((3,6), dtype='bool')
>>> mask[np.ix_([0,2],[0,2,4,5])] = True
>>> mask
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True]])
```

You can then take advantage of numpy array broadcasting rules apply the mask to the array and sum over the last dimensions:

```
>>> new_sum = np.sum(e * mask.reshape(1,1,3,6), axis=(2,3))
>>> new_sum
array([[ 70, 214, 358],
       [502, 646, 790]])
```

Here is a small code that compares the performances of the two versions on a bigger matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import time

N, P = 200, 100
e = np.arange(18*N*P).reshape(N, P, 3, 6)

t_start = time.time()
new_sum = np.empty((N,P))
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(P):
      temp_array = e[i,j,:,:]
      new_sum[i,j] = np.sum(temp_array[np.ix_([0,2],[0,2,4,5])])
print(f'Timer 1: {time.time()-t_start}s')

t_start = time.time()
mask = np.zeros((3,6), dtype='bool')
mask[np.ix_([0,2],[0,2,4,5])] = True
new_sum_2 = np.sum(e * mask.reshape(1,1,3,6), axis=(2,3))
print(f'Timer 2: {time.time()-t_start}s')

print('Results are equal!' if np.allclose(new_sum, new_sum_2) else 'Results differ!')
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
Timer 1: 0.4343228340148926s
Timer 2: 0.002004384994506836s
Results are equal!
```

As you can see you get a significant improvement in terms of computation time.

Answer (score 1):

Just a [slight extension of your own idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) really: give some more dimensions to `np.ix_`, and then sum over the last two axes.

```
import numpy as np

e = np.arange(108).reshape(2, 3, 3, 6)

indices = [[0,2], [0,2,4,5]]

print(
  np.sum(e[np.ix_(*[range(i) for i in e.shape[:-2]], *indices)], axis=(-2,-1))
)
```

This gives:

```
array([[ 70, 214, 358],
       [502, 646, 790]])
```

So the arguments to `np.ix_` in this case are

```
range(2), range(3), [0,2], [0,2,4,5]
```

For a bit more generality, we could also refrain from making assumptions about the number of axes used in the indices list:

```
np.sum(e[np.ix_(*[range(i) for i in e.shape[:-len(indices)]], *indices)],
       axis=tuple(range(-len(indices),0)))
```

*(Data type will be the same as for `e`, which would have been the case in the example in the question if the same data type had been specified when calling `np.empty`.  I'm assuming there's no particular reason to cast to `np.float`.)*

Answer (score 1):

A slightly faster approach (if your array is large and selected indices are small) than sum (same idea) as @alaniwi's solution:

```
  np.einsum('ijkl->ij',e[np.ix_(np.arange(e.shape[0]),np.arange(e.shape[1]),[0,2],[0,2,4,5])])

[[ 70, 214, 358],
 [502, 646, 790]]
```